# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm working on a project for school using Xamarin. I'm not super familiar with Xamarin so I will try my best to explain my issue. My App has a Courses Page and a Add New Courses Page. When clicking on `Add New Course` I get the error: **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation**. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and have spend 10+ hours trying to figure this out. Is there a better way to navigate to a desired page?

For the requirements of the project, I am limited to running on Android only using Pie 9.0 - API 28

CoursesPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:FinalTestProject.ViewModels" 
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:FinalTestProject.Models"
         x:Class="FinalTestProject.Views.CoursesPage"
         Title="{Binding Title}">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:CoursesModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add New Course" Command="{Binding NavigateToAddNewCoursePageCommand}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<ListView
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Course}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
    RefreshControlColor="Red"
    SelectionMode="None"
    SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Course">
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem/>
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            </Grid>
                            <Button Text="Delete" WidthRequest="100" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
                            <Label FontSize="Medium"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="{Binding CourseId}"/>
                            <Label FontSize ="Small"
                                   Text="{Binding CourseName}"/>
                            <Label FontSize="Small"
                                   Text="{Binding InstructorFirstName}"/>
                            <Label FontSize="Small"
                                   Text="{Binding InstructorLastName}"/>
                            <Label FontSize="Small"
                                   Text="{Binding AssessmentType}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

AddNewCoursePage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:FinalTestProject.ViewModels"
         x:DataType="viewmodels:AddNewCourseModel"
         x:Class="FinalTestProject.Views.AddNewCoursePage"
         Title="{Binding Title}">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:AddNewCourseModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Spacing="3" Padding="15">
            <Label Text="Course Name" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding CourseName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="Instructor's First Name" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding InstructorFirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="Instructor's Last Name" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding InstructorLastName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="Notes" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Editor Text="{Binding Notes, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="Small" AutoSize="TextChanges"/>
            <Label Text="Start Date" FontSize="Small"/>
            <DatePicker Date="{Binding CourseStartDate}"/>
            <Label Text="End Date" FontSize="small"/>
            <DatePicker Date="{Binding CourseEndDate}"/>
            <Label Text="Assessment Type" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Picker BindingContext="{Binding }">
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>Objective</x:String>
                    <x:String>Performance</x:String>
                </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding AddCourseCommand}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
                <Button Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

CoursesModel.cs

```
public class CoursesModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public ObservableRangeCollection<Course> AllCourses { get; set; }
    public AsyncCommand RefreshCommand { get; }
    public AsyncCommand NavigateToAddNewCoursePageCommand { get; }

    public CoursesModel()
    {
        Title = "Courses";

        AllCourses = new ObservableRangeCollection<Course>();
        RefreshCommand = new AsyncCommand(Refresh);
        NavigateToAddNewCoursePageCommand = new AsyncCommand(NavigateToAddNewCoursePage);
    }

    async Task NavigateToAddNewCoursePage()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AddNewCoursePage));
    }

    async Task Refresh()
    {
        Busy();

        AllCourses.Clear();
        var courses = await CourseService.GetAllCourses();
        AllCourses.AddRange(courses);

        NotBusy();
    }
}
```

AddNewCourseModel

public class AddNewCourseModel : BaseViewModel
{
private string courseName;

```
    public AsyncCommand AddCourseCommand { get; }
    public AsyncCommand CancelCommand { get; }

    public AddNewCourseModel()
    {
        Title = "Add New Course";

        AddCourseCommand = new AsyncCommand(AddCourse);
        CancelCommand = new AsyncCommand(Cancel);
    }

    async Task AddCourse()
    {

        var course = new Course()
        {
             CourseName = CourseName

        };
        await CourseService.AddCourse(course);
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("CoursesPage");

    }

    async Task Cancel()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("CoursesPage");
    }

    public string CourseName
    {
        get => courseName;
        set => SetProperty(ref courseName, value);
    }
}
```

AddNewCoursePage.xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class AddNewCoursePage : ContentPage
{
    public AddNewCoursePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(CoursesPage), typeof(CoursesPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AddNewCoursePage), typeof(AddNewCoursePage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TermsPage), typeof(TermsPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AddNewTermPage), typeof(AddNewTermPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is look for the *nested* exception which will show the original exception that was thrown. Use the `Exception.InnerException` property - or just log the whole exception and it should be there.

Comment: you need to look at the `InnerException` property to get more detail on the root cause of the error

Comment: Each ```InnerException``` is set to ```(null)```. @JonSkeet when you say "Log the whole exception" what do you mean? How would I do that? Pardon my elementary knowledge :)

Comment: I don't remember *every* seeing a `TargetInvocationException` with a null InnerException. By "log the whole exception" I mean log the results of calling `ToString` on it. That should include any nested exceptions.

Comment: @JonSkeet After looking deeper, I was able to look at the inner exception. The error I got was ```Cannot implicitly convert "small" to 'double'```. If you look at my **AddNewCoursePage.xaml** page above, you can see for ```<Label Text="End Date" FontSize="small"/>``` the string **small** is lowercase and the rest are uppercase.

After spending 10+ hours working on this, I wish there was a better way for xaml error logging. I'm happy it was an easy fix, but disappointed on the lack of error logging. Thank your for your help with looking at the inner exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think it occur error on xaml.

CoursesPage.xaml

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Course , Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

AddNewCoursePage.xaml

every "Mode=TwoWay" delete. except Datepicker
.

Comment: You did see that the problem turned out to be a typo and was already solved?